# How do we know if someone has successfully discovered the steps of a hashing algorithm?

Tags: hash, sha-256

I was reading an article about how SHA-256 encrypts stuff ([Here](https://qvault.io/cryptography/how-sha-2-works-step-by-step-sha-256/) it is by the way) but how do we know the steps mentioned are true? I'm not a cryptography expert but I've tried making my own encryption algorithm with python by switching up the order of the letters and doing other text manipulation steps (which I've found to be bad since doing so would pose a security risk if you don't know what you're doing) and I've tried incorporating SHA-256 in the program. The hashing happened in less than 3 seconds. So how does the article mentioned know what SHA-256 is really doing and has anyone found a way to crack it yet?

**EDIT:** I think I need to rephrase my question. What I'm trying to say is this. Cryptography experts try to figure out how hashing algorithms work. But what I'm trying to figure out is, how do they know, for example, that the first step in the SHA-256 algorithm is to convert everything into binary? How do they figure out the rest of the steps?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you believe that the SHA256 algorithm itself is secret? Are you asking "how can we be sure a hash algorithm is a good one?"

Comment: I closed the question for now, for (as sated by the OP) it at least needs to be rephrased. Most hash algorithms, including SHA-256, are public. That's per the (second) [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) which rules modern cryptography. So discovery of their steps is by reading their specification. For those hashes that are not public, reverse-engineering is the way, and off-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You should read the book about the Blake hash function, it is experience and testing....

Comment: @kelalaka Any chance you have hyperlink to the Blake book?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Function-BLAKE-Information-Security-Cryptography/dp/3662447568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do we know if someone has successfully discovered the steps of a hashing algorithm?

Same way mathematicians and physicists discover formula and laws of nature, science, logic, etc. And in information technology in particular, you discover a supposedly secret "algorithm" by implementing an alleged specification of the algorithm, execute it over known data samples, and confirm whether the output match the input.

The above paragraph of text is supposed to answer the question in the title and the edit, as the paragraph explains how in general, people reverse-engineer an algorithm.

> which I've found to be bad since doing so would pose a security risk if you don't know what you're doing

Good, you've understood not to roll your own crypto.

Finally, it should be noted however, SHA-256 is not a classified algorithm. It's actually a public algorithm released in US and used world-wide. If you goto NIST's website, you can try look for NIST-FIPS-180 currently in its 4th revision. I think this question may be better received if it asks how were RC4 algorithm was discovered, as it was originally an actual trade secret.